# Is the ODBC 3.52 spec available anywhere on the internet?

Tags: odbc

Does anyone have a link to the ODBC 3.52 spec? What's up on MSDN is 3.8, and I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific question/need/concern?  Most of [the 3.8 doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inherits 3.52, and they're usually pretty good about saying [what has changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee388580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I work on a product that claims to support ODBC 3.52, so it would be nice to be able to see _exactly_ what that was. There's a similar problem with the 2.0 spec, which seems to have disappeared off the face of the internet, but we have an olllld bound copy of that at work